# How to translate matrix list index into matrix coords?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

Say you have a 2d matrix:

```js
const matrix = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
];
```

Which is represented as a list:

```js
const list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

You can easily generate the list index in the list using the following:

```js
function coordsToListIndex({ x, y }, width) {
    return x + (y * width);
}

// index = 7
const index = coordsToListIndex({ x: 1, y: 1 }, 6);
```

What is the best way to translate in the opposite direction, from list index to coordinates?

What I've come up with is as follows, but I suspect there could be a better way.

```js
function listIndexToCoords(index, width) {

    let count = 0;
    let x = 0;
    let y = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        count++;
        x++;
        if (count === index) {
            break;
        } else if (i == width - 1) {
            x = 0;
            y++;
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    return {
        x,
        y
    };
}

// cords = { x: 1, y: 1 }
const coords = listIndexToCoords(7, 6);
```

Comment: Remember that `%` exists. No need for a for loop.

Comment: As Mike says, if you’re really dead set on losing the data and regaining it, then y = floor(index / width) and x = index % width

Comment: The full scenario is a bit more complex where the indexes are what is held in an adjacency list, so being able to translate back and forth between indexes and matrix coordinates is really useful. Thanks for the tip, the % works well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on input and solutions from
Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans and shawn_halayka in the comments above.

```js
function coordsToListIndex({ x, y }, width) {
    return x + (y * width);
}

function listIndexToCoords(index, width) {
    return {
        x: index % width,
        y: Math.floor(index / width)
    };
}
```